# Making a scatter plot from the elements of two arrays

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

So, I want to create two vectors using a `For`.

Example:

```
Array[a, 5];
For[i = 1, i <= 5, i++, a[5] = i/5]
Array[b, 5];
For[i = 1, i <= 5, i++, b[5] = i/6]
```

And after that, I would like to plot the points `{a[i], b[i]}` and draw lines between them. I searched on the internet, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: `ListLinePlot[Table[{a[i], b[i]}, {i, 5}]]`?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need a `For` statement, while `Table` is far superior:

```
ListPlot[Table[{i/5, i/6}, {i, 5}], 
 Joined -> True, 
 PlotMarkers -> Green,
 PlotStyle -> Red]
```

Comment: If you want to be able to retrieve the `a` and `b` arrays later, you can set `{a, b} = Transpose@Table[{i/5, i/6}, {i, 5}]`, so that, for example, `b[[3]] == 1/2`. For plotting the `{a[i], b[i]}` points from there, use `ListPlot[Transpose@{a, b}, **options**]`.

Answer (score 2):

> *want to create two vectors **using a `For`***

(1) Assign values to `a` and `b` inside `For`:

```
For[i = 1, i <= 5, i++, a[i] = i/5]
For[i = 1, i <= 5, i++, b[i] = i/6]
```

(2a) Create data pairs directly using `Array`:

```
data = Array[{a @ #, b @ #}&, 5]
```

(2b) Alternatively, name two arrays, say `aa` and `bb`, then create pairs using `Transpose`:

```
{aa, bb} = Array[#, 5] & /@ {a, b};
data = Transpose[{aa, bb}];
```

(3) `ListPlot` `data`:

```
ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large], 
 Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> False, PlotRangePadding -> .1]
```

[image]

**Note:** You can also reverse the order of steps (1) and (2) to get the same result.

**Update:** For the case in comments:

> *But if I have a vector like this:* `For[ i=1, i<=n, i++, v[i] = Point[{i/2, i/3}]]`*, how can I plot it?*

```
n = 10;
For[i = 1, i <= n, i++, v[i] = Point[{i/2, i/3}]]
Graphics[{Red, PointSize@Large, Array[v, 10]}, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Alternatively, use `v / @ Range[10]` in place of `Array[v, 10]` to get the same result.

Comment: But if I have a vector like this: For[ i=1, i<=n, i++, v[i] = Point[{i/2, i/3}]], how can I plot it?

Comment: @Princeton, please see the update.

Comment: And having the same type of vector, how can I draw lines between the points? I can't figure out a syntax for ListLinePlot if this is what is needed.

Comment: Add `Line[Join @@ List @@@ Array[v, 10]]` after `Array[v, 10]` in `Graphics`. If you have to use `ListLinePlot` you can do `ListLinePlot[Join @@ List @@@ Array[v, 10], Epilog -> Array[v, 10]]`.